# How do i add data into a join table using TypeOrm?

Tags: node.js, typeorm

[This is the Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezmPV.png)

i want to insert data into this table through an api, it contains foreign key references like student_id and roll_id.

i commented out student_id and roll_id, so as to avoid multiple keys with the same name.

Please help me out :)

Comment: If I got your question right you wanna enter data that references PK from other table?

Comment: yes! exactly, i tried but failed :(

Comment: Okay, if you have any data just specify roll_id and student_id to data (like student_id:1, roll_id: 1) you have in db and should work like normal as db by itself looks if data exists or not.

Comment: This kinda works, but it creates duplicate columns of student_id and roll_id.

Comment: Okay I noticed where is your problem, you are referencing other column from other tables. Try to change it to PK of the tables you use and it should stop duplicating as typeorm will figure out what are connecting.

Answer (score 1):

try this for
@ManyToMany()
@JoinTable({ name: 'lead_division' })

```
const query = await createQueryBuilder('lead_divisions', 'ld').insert().values({ leadId: 1, divisionId: 1}).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're just looking for how to insert?

```js
async function saveStudentRollState(data: StudentRollState) {
  const repo = getRepository(StudentRollState);
  const savedRecord = await repo.save(data);
  return savedRecord;
}
```

Comment: Hi @danieldaugherty, i tried with a similar solution, but since it's  Join table, this solution doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

try this for Entity definition.

```
@Entity()
export class StudentRollState {
  ...
  @Column()
  student_id: number;
  
  @Column()
  roll_id: number;
  
  @ManyToOne(()=>Student, (student) => student.id)
  student: Student;
  
  @ManyToOne(()=>Roll, (roll) => roll.id)
  roll: Roll;
}
```

And now if you insert data your duplicating should go away.

Comment: Actually this worked, but i can't insert data into this table using DTO's, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you specify the PKs of other tables when you were inserting? I used this in many of my apps and it worked without problems.